# How to pass the int value from an iphone app to a server ?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am inserting data from an iphone app to a server

```
 participant_id="1";
 NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"participant_id=%@&question_id=%@&answer_text=%@&answer_option=%@",participant_id,question_id,answer_text,answer_option];
```

Using the above line with other code, Is it possible instead that `NSString participant_id` may pass `int participant _id` to server from this line

Comment: What kind of Data Type your participant_id is ?

Comment: participant_id in data base is integer

Comment: I don't think you can pass the id in integer format.Because your url itself is in string format.

Comment: You Need to pass only the NSString type so 
int participant_id = 1 ;
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"participant_id=%d", participant_id];

Comment: @VXtreme, I think he just means his variable is an integer, and hew wants to format it into a string

Comment: in this way i am doing then my application quits not working

Comment: @VXtreme yes like this as you are saying

Comment: Yes ,as answers given below we can convert the int values into string but ultimately we have to pass it into string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use the `%d` or `%u` format specifier:

```
participant_id = 1 ;
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"participant_id=%d", participant_id];
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html for the full list.